# RecyclerView Adapter with TextView

Tags: java, android

My `RecyclerView` has 3 columns in a single row. 2 are populated from a `SQLite` database query and the other with a `TextView`. I'm having troubles with how to have the `TextView` populate. The goal is to have the `TextView` be set via options of Strings chosen from a set of switch statements. However, `findViewById` cannot be resolved. Is there a way to have a `TextView` inside `onBindViewHolder`?

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class UpcomingRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpcomingRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Cursor mCursor;


public UpcomingRecyclerViewAdapter(Cursor cursor) {
    this.mCursor = cursor;
}

@Override
public UpcomingRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_list_items, parent, false);
    return new UpcomingRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UpcomingRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if ((mCursor != null) && (mCursor.getCount() != 0)) {
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(VehiclesContract.Columns.VEHICLE_NAME));
        String miles = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(VehiclesContract.Columns.VEHICLE_CURRENT));
        String maintenance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.up_list_maintenance);

        holder.name.setText(name);
        holder.miles.setText(miles);
        holder.maintenance.setText(maintenance);
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursor != null ? mCursor.getCount() : 0;
}


static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView miles;
    TextView maintenance;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upcoming_name);
        this.miles = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upcoming_miles);
        this.maintenance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upcoming_maintenance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to make your `TextView`'s global and get them with id in `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: if your main goal is only set Text in maintenance use ... so store string in string resources and get vie contextObject.getResources().getString(R.string.maintenance_string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, in this line

```
String maintenance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.up_list_maintenance);
```

you are trying to **assign** a **view** to **a string**, that is sheerly wrong.

You can either `assign the value of a textfield which is a string to a string variable`,

or `assign a textfield to a variable of textfield type.`

Fix this first and, then see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String maintenance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.up_list_maintenance);
```

findViewById returns a View. You are trying to cast it a string. Try this:

```
String maintenance = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.up_list_maintenance)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: sir there are no view object create please read angain the code